# Why is my decimal rounding to 1 significant figure?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My stopwatch I'm using to execute code is rounding to one significant figure for no apparent reason at all.

---

`FormTime` is defined manually from `FORM`
I've trimmed it down from `FORM=[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],` to just include the time for debugging purposes

```py
FORM=[[1], [1.875], [2.25], [4.562], [5.438]]
```

---

`stopwatch` is defined from the following;

```py
import datetime
from math import floor
```

```py
a = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
        
    b = datetime.datetime.now()
    c = (b - a)
    roundMicro = floor(c.microseconds/1e3)
    stopwatch = float(str(c.seconds)+'.'+str(roundMicro))

    ...
```

`stopwatch` running in loop outputs;

```py
>>> stopwatch
0.0
...
0.123
...
0.2
```

---

For example here is the time it's meant to execute (`FormTime`) vs when it actually executes (`Ex` which is just `stopwatch`)

```py
count = 0
a = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
        
    b = datetime.datetime.now()
    c = (b - a)
    roundMicro = floor(c.microseconds/1e3)
    stopwatch = float(str(c.seconds)+'.'+str(roundMicro))
    

    if FORM[count][0]<=stopwatch:
        
        print(f'FormTime = {FORM[count][0]}', end="")
        print(f'{" "*int(7-len(str(FORM[count][0])))}', end="") #Just decorative spacing in terminal
        print(f'Ex ≈ {stopwatch}') #Ex = Executed @
        count+=1
```

Returns;

```
FormTime = 1      Ex ≈ 1.0
FormTime = 1.875  Ex ≈ 1.9
FormTime = 2.25   Ex ≈ 2.3
FormTime = 4.562  Ex ≈ 4.6
FormTime = 5.438  Ex ≈ 5.5
```

---

Any idea why it executes when `stopwatch` = one significant digit?
Or why it's rounding?

- Don't mind the `Exception has occurred: IndexError list index out of range, line 21` this is intended to occur at the end of the demo

Comment: I ran your code, and at second example I got the output [1.88]

Comment: Just stop dividing it by `1e3` and remove `floor`.

Comment: What will happen when `count>len(FORM)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
roundMicro = floor(c.microseconds/1e3)
stopwatch = float(str(c.seconds)+'.'+str(roundMicro))
```

These two lines probably aren't what you're expecting. Assume `c.microseconds == 3000`, you'll get `roundMicro = 3` and end up with `1.3` when it should be `1.003`.

Reinventing the wheels isn't necessary here unless you're learning about mathematical rounding. Use format strings to get your desired precision (and optionally, layout):

```
stopwatch = "{:.3f}".format(c.seconds + c.microseconds * 1e-6)
# => 1.003
```

And if you need the truncated value as a number, you can still call `float(stopwatch)` to convert the string.